# can an XML element have textNode AND childelements?

Tags: xml

Is SomeText ok in XML node, if there are Childnodes? Is the below code valid?

```
<main att="123">SomeText
    <child>sample</child>
</main>
```

Comment: Would the down-voter care to explain why?  This looks like a perfectly fine question to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether your example is a *valid* XML document depends on the Document Type Definition you wish to validate it against.  It is [*well-formed*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_document), tough.  That is, nothing in the XML specification forbids you to write such documents.

Comment: The xml is valid, but json_encode() fails on this.
I did a rewrite of the php function [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27633518/how-to-get-json-from-xml-string)

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to have text and child elements, see: http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_complex_mixed.asp

It depends on the xsd that you are validating against.